# Vue watch route

Tags: routes, vue.js

I have a problem, because I need t check or there was changed route.
My example adress is :

```
htttp://mySite/#/list/orders/actual
```

and

```
http://mySite/#/list/visits/actual
```

I have template and in there I'm chceckig or the route was changed. This is single page:

```
<template>
<section>
    <div>{{ header }}</div>
</section>
</template>
<script>
   export default {

    name: 'headers',
    data: () => ({
        header: 'Here should be dynamicly changed header',
    }),
    watch: {
        '$route'(to, from) {

        }
    },
    methods: {}
}
```

How to check or now I'm on the list? orders and visits are params, and I can check them very simple, but list is not a param. How to check or I'm now on the list? I need to fetch this data from url because I have another adresses like : http://mySite/#/something/orders

Answer (score 0):

[You could add metadata to the route](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html)

Adding metadata to a route is simple:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      meta: { 
        pageCategory: 'list'
      }
    },

    {
      path: '/bar',
      component: Bar,
      meta: { 
        pageCategory: 'something'
      }
    }

  ]
})
```

This page meta can then be accessed inside your watcher by using `to.matched.meta.pageCategory`, and then you can do whatever you want using it.